# access entity query result from another func

Tags: c#, linq, entity, ienumerable

hi i have this query in func 1 and i want access to this query from func 2 how i can do this?

func 1:

```
var data = db.Question.Where(x => x.GroupId == id)
                      .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                      .Take(Convert.ToInt32(txtTedad.Text));
```

func 2:

```
if (answerlist.Items[i].ToString() == data.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(index).Id.ToString())
{
    sahih = sahih + 1;
}
```

can i create a global variable and assign query result to my variable? something like this:

```
VarType mydata;

func1(){
    mydata = query;
}

func2(){
    mydata.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(index).Id.ToString()
}
```

Comment: What are the function signatures? The first one could return `data` and the second one could take a parameter that accepts it.

Comment: i just want to pass variable to another variable

Comment: @PowerCode I just noticed something strange, why would you order the answers by Guid.NewGuid()?  That would mean the questions are not ordered so our solution will give unexpected results :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly what you were trying to achieve, but I think it is something like the code below. The code and the design can be greatly simplified and/or improved, but this would be a step in the right direction. This is merely an example to illustrate how you can achieve what you described you wanted.

```
private IQueryable<Question> getQuestionAnswers(int questionCount, int studentID)
{
   return db.Question.Where(x => x.GroupId == studentId)
                      .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                      .Take(questionCount);
}

private int calculateStudentScore(int studentId, .... answerList)
{
    int studentScore = 0;
    var studentAnswers = getQuestionAnswers(answerList.Length, studentId).ToList();
   //research IEnumerable.Zip for more fun ways to calculate the score (zip required answers and student answers and just sum over the resulting list where answers are equal to obtain the score

    for (int i = 0; i < answerList.Length; i++)
    {
       //if (answerlist check against studentAnswers)
       {
            studentscore++;
       }
    }

    return studentScore;
}
```

In short, you do not need to PASS a function to another for what you need, you simply call one function from the other!